# What is optimal performance for set merge algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, set-difference, set-intersection, set-union

Assume ordered sets that support O(n) iteration and O(log n) access to single items, what is theoretically optimal complexity for set-union, set-intersection and set-difference? Assume that a dedicated structure could be used for the sets, as long as the result is of the same type as the input.

Edit:

Let n be the size of the larger set, m the size of the smaller set and d the size of the symmetric difference.

An algorithm is described [in this paper.](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~scandal/papers/treaps-spaa98.pdf) It runs in O(m*log(n/m)) which is claimed to be optimal.
The algorithm is then modified [in this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1301.3388) so that it also becomes O(d*log(n/d)).

Is it a contradiction that an optimal algorithm can be improved? I guess not since d is a new parameter, O(m*log(n/m)) is still optimal with respect to n and m. But is this the end or how fast is possible?

Comment: What are your suggestions so far? Sounds like homework. Think how you would implement `set-union`, `set-intersection` and `set-difference` using the given set interface.

Comment: The best algorithm I have found so far run in O(min(m*log(n/m),d*log(n/d)), where n is the size of the larger set, m is the size of the smaller set and d is the size of the symmetric difference. But is this optimal or can it be improved further?

Comment: You can't get that running time unless the abstract data type has more operations than you've admitted to.

Comment: It is assumed the items can be compared and hashed in O(1). Do you have other operations in mind?